# Create Json string using JsonObject in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to use JsonObject class in C# to create a Json string.

I am trying to use the Add method on the Json object to add a key value pair of string, string.

```
var jsonObject = new JsonObject();

jsonObject.Add("PlayerLevel", "3");
```

The value part is looking for an IJsonValue object and doesn't like me just passing "3"

Annoyingly other examples I have seen online don't appear to have this restriction and allow people to simply add text / numbers

of course I could create a class that implements this interface but it feels like lots of work for something I'm thinking should be simple.

Also I know that other options are available for creating Json string but for other reasons this is the method I am electing to use.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks
Matt

Comment: Maybe I did not understand the question correctly but is this what you need var jsonObject = new JObject();?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer almost immediately after posting this.

I found the JsonValue.CreateStringValue method

```
 var jsonValue = JsonValue.CreateStringValue(record.Value);
```

I could then pass this into the Add method on the JsonObject.